# What is difference between 'url.searchParams' and 'URLSearchParams' in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

What is the main difference between `URLSearchParams()` and `url.searchParams`?

How are these different?

```
var searchParams = new URLSearchParams("q=URLUtils.searchParams&topic=api");

url = new URL(document.URL);

urlsrchprm = url.searchParams;
```

Comment: Why speak about node.js and even tag it with when your example has `document.URL`?

Answer (score 1):

Both returns `URLSearchParams` object. So end result would be the same.

The differece is, in the case of `URLSearchParams()` you're using the constructor directly.

While in this case `url.searchParams` you're using `searchParams` method of `URL` object.

Example:

```js
function A(x) {
  this.foo = x;
}
var a = new A('bar');
console.log(a.foo)

function B(x) {
  this.baz = x;
  this.test = function() {
    return new A(this.baz);
  }
}
var b = new B('bar');
var c = b.test();
console.log(c.foo)
```

Answer (score 1):

Until now, I believed that both were identical, and documents also indicated the same. However, there is a slight distinction in how they are accessed. One utilizes the URL object, while the other is a standalone class.

In this context, url.searchParams lacks access to parameters after the hash, whereas URLSearchParams can access them, allowing you to retrieve the values of those parameters.

This discrepancy may be a bug, as url.searchParams is of type URLSearchParams, but the output is entirely different.

You can verify this in the code snippet below.

```js
const myURL = "https://my313815.host.com/ui?ui-version=untested&ui-debug=ui/generic/#so-a&/C_ARPostingRule(PostingRuleUUID=guid'abcd',IsActiveEntity=true)/?hasparam1=AS0REUAY6MZ32TWR56I6U7S8V53EKRGCKDHOW3VB&ui-xx-cardTitle=ManagePurchaseOrder&hashparam2=TASCRXFQ1JKDTO58DTIFMZOQQED762V9Y46X0F5UV";

const url = new URL(myURL);
const urlSearchParam = new URLSearchParams(myURL);

const hasCardTitleInUrl = url.searchParams.has('ui-xx-cardTitle');
const hasCardTitleInUrlSearchParam = urlSearchParam.has('ui-xx-cardTitle');

console.log('ui-xx-cardTitle:', hasCardTitleInUrl);
console.log('ui-xx-cardTitle:', hasCardTitleInUrlSearchParam);
```

Comment: That's not how you're supposed to use `URLSearchParams`. Here `urlSearchParam.has("https://my313815.host.com/ui?ui-version")` would return `true`.

Comment: If that's the case then urlSearchParam.get('ui-xx-cardTitle') should not give me proper output.

Comment: Why not? You're supposed to pass an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` string, so it will just split your input at `&` characters and then split the results at `=` characters and generate your output. So yes, the `ui-xx-cardTitle=ManagePurchaseOrder` part will be parsed correctly, but it will not contain an `ui-version` entry though, since it will grab all the URL before the search into the key. I mean, just ask your console what `new URLSearchParams(myURL)` produces.

Answer (score 0):

`new URLSearchParams(url.search)` would be the same as `url.searchParams`. But that's about it.

To generate the `URL` instance on which you access the `.searchParams` property, you need to pass a full URL. While the `URLSearchParams` constructor expects a string in the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format (i.e. the part that comes after `?` in the *search* part of an URL), or a dictionary, or a sequence of couple of strings.

So they just don't have the same signature to begin with, and thus you can never use one instead of the other.